# Cannot Compile "Hello World" in NetBeans IDE 7.3 with MinGW C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

I'm trying to make a simple "Hello World!" program in NetBeans IDE 7.3 with MinGW as my C++ compiler.

I'm getting build failures and I'm at a loss as to understanding why.

This is my compiler setup:

- Family: **MinGW**
- Base Directory: **C:\MinGW**
- C Compiler: **C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe**
- C++ Compiler: **C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe**
- Assembler: **C:\MinGW\bin\as.exe**
- Make Command: **C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe**
- Debugger Command: **C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe**

I've made sure to that my environment PATH directs to **C:\MinGW\bin** and **C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin**.

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

After trying to build the project, I recieve this message from the NetBeans debug output:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorld'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/helloworld.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorld'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
make[2]: g++: Command not found
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorld'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorld'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

I've search various Q&A, but I seem to be doing everything correctly.

Comment: Does `C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe` exist?

Comment: Indeed it does. I'm rather baffled by this.

Comment: I haven't used NetBeans IDE. Perhaps it needs some specific configuration to find `g++` and friends. Or, if you changed your `PATH` recently, perhaps NetBeans doesn't have your updated `PATH`; in that case, shutting down and restarting NetBeans might fix it.

Comment: None of your configured commands are being used - the location of `make` in your setup is `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe`, but the log shows that `/usr/bin/make` is being used; your setup indicates that the C++ compiler is `C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe`, but `g++` is being invoked (with no path).  There's a major disconnect between your compiler setup and how the project is trying to build.

Comment: Ah! That worked! I should have done so earlier. Thank you very much, Mr. Thompson! I'll continue my studies.

Comment: @ Michael Burr: I'm not sure why that message is coming as such. I have stated the relevant paths. However, all seems to be fine now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on My Computer and select properties. Click Advanced System Settings.System Properties dialog box will open. click Environmental Variables. Edit PATH variable and add C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin

Comment: The path may be C:\msys\1.0\bin if you installed it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Your settings on netbeans shoud be as follows

```
Base Directory: C:\MinGW\bin 
C Compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe 
C++ Compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe 
Fortran Compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe 
Assembler: C:\MinGW\bin\as.exe 
Make Command: C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe 
Debbuger Command: C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe
```

Add these to your Environment variables

```
C:\MinGW\bin and C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
```

This can happen if you have set the settings on netbeans before/during the time of installing MINGW and setting the environment PATH.

Just restart netbeans

Answer (score -2):

you download mysys form mingw or sourceforge.net after install it, path is C:\Mysys\1.0\bin\make.exe  to give the path into make compiler in netbean ide.

Comment: this is not the fix for this issue