# Netbeans First Time Compiler Build Error

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-construction, mingw

I recently decided to try NetBeans, and upon downloading and linking MinGW was greeted with the following error when trying to compiler a "Hello World" program.

```
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/David/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_2'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/welcome_2.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/David/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_2'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows
make.exe[2]: mkdir: Command not found
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/welcome.o] Error 127
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/David/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_2'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/David/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_2'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

For my options under tools\options\c/c++\Build Tools I have
Base Directory: C:\MinGW32\bin

C Compiler: C:\MinGW32\bin\gcc.exe

C++ Compiler: C:\MinGW32\bin\g++.exe

Assembler: C:\MinGW32\bin\as.exe

Make Command: C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe

Debugger Command: C:\MinGW32\bin\gdb.exe

It's possible that I could have just linked something wrong, but if it would be easier to reinstall some stuff, then I am open to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the similarity to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324451/cannot-compile-hello-world-in-netbeans-ide-7-3-with-mingw-c), shutting down and restarting Netbeans might fix this issue (by updating your`PATH`).

Here's hoping it is that easy!